# How can I use suspend function or viewModelScope/lifecycleScope in WebSocketListener?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

I implemented WebSocket with WebSocketListener. And I want to use coroutine channel.
But now I need to call it in Coroutine Scope. Here, I don't have viewModelScope nor lifecycleScope. So, I used GlobalScope. And I think this might cause memory leak and incorrect behaviour.

```
@OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
class CustomWebSocketListener : WebSocketListener() {
    val socketEventChannel: Channel<SocketUpdate> = Channel(10)

    override fun onOpen(webSocket: WebSocket, response: Response) {
        // no-op
    }

    override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, text: String) {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            socketEventChannel.sendOrNothing(SocketUpdate(text = text))
        }
    }

    override fun onClosing(webSocket: WebSocket, code: Int, reason: String) {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            socketEventChannel.sendOrNothing(SocketUpdate(exception = SocketAbortedException()))
        }
        webSocket.close(1000, null)
        socketEventChannel.close()
    }

    override fun onFailure(webSocket: WebSocket, t: Throwable, response: Response?) {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            socketEventChannel.sendOrNothing(SocketUpdate(exception = t))
        }
    }

    private suspend fun <E> Channel<E>.sendOrNothing(e: E) {
        try {
            this.send(e)
        } catch (e: ClosedSendChannelException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

I use CustomWebSocketListener like this:

```
    suspend fun startOrReloadSocket(url: String): Channel<SocketUpdate> {
        if(isConnected()) {
            if(url == webSocketUrl) {
                return webSocketListener!!.socketEventChannel
            } else {
                stopSocket()
            }
        }
        return with(CustomWebSocketListener()) {
            startOrReloadSocket(url,this)
            this@with.socketEventChannel
        }
    }
```

I made this for using the listener. How can I include the listener in the same coroutine scope so that I can use viewModelScope?(the suspend function(startOrReloadSocket) is called in the viewModelScope)

Comment: Why not use `trySend`?

Comment: does `startOrReloadSocket` exist in your VM? if so, you can pass a scope through that function to the constructor of `CustomWebSocketListener` or use something like `trySend` as Ethan suggested

Comment: @EthanChoi I don't know it is used.. can you explain more?

Comment: @WilliamReed sending scope to listener class looks weird because I feel like listener doesn't receive anything but only listens something.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use suspend function or viewModelScope/lifecycleScope in WebSocketListener?

#### produce with trySend, consume on Lifecycle

`eventChannel` isn’t `rendezvous` channel. thus, you just event produce with `trySend` and consume on lifecycle.

**Produce**

```java
/**
* If you want handle result of event produce :
*
* ChannelResult result = socketEventChannel.trySend(~)
* if(result.isFailure) {
*    handle error
* }
**/

override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, text: String) {
    socketEventChannel.trySend(SocketUpdate(text = text))
}

override fun onClosing(webSocket: WebSocket, code: Int, reason: String) {
    socketEventChannel.trySend(SocketUpdate(exception = SocketAbortedException()))
    webSocket.close(1000, null)
    socketEventChannel.close()
}

override fun onFailure(webSocket: WebSocket, t: Throwable, response: Response?) {
    socketEventChannel.trySend(SocketUpdate(exception = t))
}
```

**Consume**

```java
viewModelScope or lifecycleScope.launch {
    listener.socketEventChannel.consumeEach {
        // TODO : handle socket event
    }
}
```

#### Ref

[trySend](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-send-channel/try-send.html)